# I need the (Submit this form )button to be clicked automatically when the page loads (WORDPRESS)

Tags: php, wordpress

iam customizing a page in wordpress , i dont need the user to see this page when it loads , so i need the Sumnit this form button to be clicked automatically the moment this page loads-for security reasons-...the user doesnt need to fill anything on this form.

this is the button code:

```
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submitBtn" type="submit"value="Submit This Form" /></td>
```

and this is the complete code:

```
[insert_php]
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$dateTime= date('Y:m:d-H:i:s');

function getDateTime() {
    global $dateTime;                
    return $dateTime;       
}

function createHash($chargetotal,$Currency) {

    $storeId = "330995001";

    $sharedSecret = "sharedsecret";

    $dateTime= date('Y:m:d-H:i:s');

    $stringToHash = $storeId . $dateTime . $chargetotal . $Currency . 
 $sharedSecret;

    $ascii = bin2hex($stringToHash);

    return sha1($ascii);
}

[/insert_php]
IPG Connect Sample for PHP(hashing)
<h1>Order Form</h1>
&nbsp;
[insert_php]
    $responseSuccessURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8006/wordpress/?page_id=27";
    $responseFailURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8006/wordpress/?page_id=31";
[/insert_php]
<form action="https://test.ipg-online.com/connect/gateway/processing" 
method="post"><input name="timezone" type="hidden" value="IST" />
<input name="authenticateTransaction" type="hidden" value="true" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Transaction Type</td>
<td><input name="txntype" size="50" type="text" value="sale" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Transaction Date Time</td>
<td><input name="txndatetime" size="50" type="text" value="[insert_php] echo 
$dateTime; [/insert_php]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Calculated HASH</td>
<td><input name="hash" size="50" type="text" value="[insert_php] echo 
createHash("1","356"); [/insert_php]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Currency</td>
<td><input name="currency" size="50" type="text" value="356" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Payment Mode</td>
<td><input name="mode" size="50" type="text" value="payonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Store Id</td>
<td><input name="storename" size="50" type="text" value="330995001" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chargetotal</td>
<td><input name="chargetotal" size="50" type="text" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shared Secret</td>
<td><input name="sharedsecret" size="50" type="text" value="sharedsecret" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Language</td>
<td><select name="language">
<option value="de_DE">Deutsch</option>
<option selected="selected" value="en_EN">English</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="responseSuccessURL" value="[insert_php] echo 
$responseSuccessURL; [/insert_php]"/>           
<input type="hidden" name="responseFailURL" value="[insert_php] echo 
 $responseFailURL; [/insert_php]"/>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submitBtn" type="submit" 
 value="Submit This Form" /></td>
 </tr>
 <input type="hidden" name="hash_algorithm" value="SHA1"/>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </form>&nbsp;
 [/insert_php]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with **Javascript**, you can do it like

```
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("formId").submit();   
 };
```

You can do it with **JQuery** like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#formId" ).submit(
});
</script>
```

I am submitting form directly, you can click on submit button as well that will do that submit operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger after document is ready,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
    });
</script>
```

Just replace the `foo` with your submit button ID

Comment: should i add this trigger before [/insert_php] or after ?

Comment: You can place this trigger in footer after php code.

Comment: If it gives any jquery error that just replace $ with jQuery , also include jQuery file if not included yet

Comment: it doesnt do anything !